# Sequelize 1:N no association found

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, eager-loading

I have 2 models: **User** and **Foto** where each User can have **N** Fotos and each Foto is assciate with **1** User.

So what i need is to eager load the Foto(i pass a specific id to retrive the foto) and the user associated to that foto.

My **User** model

```
"use strict";
var sequelize = require('./index');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var Foto = require('./Foto');

module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isUnique: function (value, next) {
          var self = this;
          User.find({ where: { username: value } })
            .then(function (user) {
              // reject if a different user wants to use the same username
              if (user && self.id !== user.id) {
                return next('username already in use!');
              }
              return next();
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              return next(err);
            });
        }
      }
    },

    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isUnique: function (value, next) {
          var self = this;
          User.find({ where: { email: value } })
            .then(function (user) {
              // reject if a different user wants to use the same email
              if (user && self.id !== user.id) {
                return next('Email already in use!');
              }
              return next();
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
              return next(err);
            });
        }
      }
    },

    typeOfUser: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull:true,
      defaultValue:null
    },

    country: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:true,
      defaultValue:null
    },

    birthDate:{
      type: DataTypes.DATEONLY,
      allowNull:true,
      defaultValue:null
    },

    reports: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    },

    points: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    },

    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull:false
    },

    numberFotos: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    }
  }, {
      classMethods: {
        generateHash: function (password) {
          return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
        },
        associate: function(models){
          User.hasMany(models.Foto,{foreignKey: "userId"});
        }

      },
      instanceMethods: {
        validPassword: function (password) {
          return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
        }
      }

    });

  return User;
}
```

important part:

```
   associate: function(models){
      User.hasMany(models.Foto,{foreignKey: "userId"});
    }
```

**My Foto model:**

```
"use strict";
var sequelize = require('./index');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var User = require('./User');


module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var Foto = sequelize.define("Foto", {
    reports: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    image: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    date: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: true
    },
    lat: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    lon: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    altitude: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    },
    plantId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
  },
    {
      associate: function (models) {
        Foto.belongsTo(models.User);
      }
    }
  );


  return Foto;
}
```

**important part:**

```
{
      associate: function (models) {
        Foto.belongsTo(models.User);
      }
    }
```

**And in my controller i try to eager load like this:**

```
  allPictures: function (req, res) {
        Foto.findAll({include: [{model: User, as: 'User'}]})
        .then(function (fotos) {
            res.send(fotos);
        })
    }
```

Comment: If you defined `as` property in relation, you should also pass `as` param in include. In your case you defined `belongsTo` without `as` param. So query should be `Foto.findAll({include: [{model: User}]})`

Comment: Already tried without it, still doesn't work :/

Comment: try to add `as` prop in association and query